# Make Folder a symbolic link to two folders?

Tags: directory, sync, dropbox, symbolic-link

I would like to have Ubuntu's default music folder `/home/$USER/Music` to act pretty much as a library would in Windows. Essentially it would be a virtual folder containing the contents of other folders.

My rationale is Rhythm Box will only watch one folder for new music. All my music resides in two folders `/home/$USER/Dropbox/Music` and `/home/$USER/Dropbox/New Music`.

This also prove useful to show the contents of other Dropbox folders in Ubuntu's default folders (Documents, Pictures, etc).

I did search and tried to find the answer on my own to no avail. I'm sure there is a way to accomplish this; I'm just missing it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is the ability to bind 2 folders together with: `sudo mount --bind olddir newdir` but this is probably not exactly what you are after...

Comment: @andrew.46 `mount --bind` allows access to one set of folder from two different mount points. OP wants to access two sets of folders from one mount point

Comment: @Edid: Oops, you are of course perfectly correct... sorry for the noise...

Comment: I could think of a way, but it would require a small background script. Would that be acceptable?

Comment: @JacobVlijm Please don't tell me the script will check if any file is available on the directory and copy to two destinations afterwards..

Comment: @heemayl I thought you'd know me better then that.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Haha..crashed in head :)

Comment: @heemayl soft links however will behave like files as far as it comes to applications. relatively easy to keep (links to) files in a "library-" folder synchronized with real files in several folders at once. I am pretty sure that is how windows "libraries" works under the hood as well. Simply comparing lists is resource- efficient.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/179404/70524

Comment: Hi @DanHutter, could you give some feedback on the answer(s)?

Comment: I apologize for the delay in response. I gave up on my quest and forgot about posting this question until I got an email notice.

Seeing as I won't be implementing it, how does it work? Do I mark the answer which seems most feasible as the correct one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Scripted solution(s)

### 1. Automatically updated library view

With the background script below, you can set up a directory, virtually showing the combined content of an arbitrary number of other folders.

The content of the folder (existing of symlinks) is dynamically synchronized with the (combined) sources.

#### How it works

The script periodically lists the content of the source folders as well as the targeted folder for the "library" -view.

- If there are items in any of the source folders, *not* existing in the library, a symlink will be created in the library.
- if there are items in the library, *not* existing in any of the source folders (actually a broken link), the item is *removed* from the library.

[image]

Comparing lists is extremely light weight (programmatically)  and low on resources. I tested the script with a much faster loop then in the script below, with a number of items of about 500 in a single directory level, with no additional (noticable) load whatsoever.

#### The script and how to use

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import sys
import time

# --- set loop time below (or leave it as it is)
loop = 5
# ---
# don't change anything below

target = sys.argv[1]
sources = sys.argv[2:]

while True:
    currlinks = os.listdir(target)
    compare = []
    for dr in sources:
        for f in os.listdir(dr):
            compare.append(f)
            if not f in currlinks:
                # create link
                os.symlink(dr+"/"+f, target+"/"+f)
    # clean up possible broken links
    for link in currlinks:
        if not link in compare:
            os.remove(target+"/"+link)
    # loop time
    time.sleep(loop)
```

1. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `library_view.py`
2. Test- run the script with the *targeted* directory, to view the combined directories in, as *first argument*, the source directories as next arguments, e.g.:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/library_view.py /path/to/virtual_library /path/to/source1 /path/to/source2
   ```

   This command will show the content of the folders `source1` and `source2` in `virtual_library`.
3. If all works fine, add it to startup applications: Dash > Startup Applications > Add. Add the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/library_view.py /path/to/virtual_library /path/to/source1 /path/to/source2
   ```

#### Note

As mentioned, you can add more than two soure directories if you like.

### 2. Manual version

If you would prefer not to use a background script for some reason, you can manually update (synchronize) the library folder, with exactly the same command under a shortcut key, using the script below:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import sys

target = sys.argv[1]
sources = sys.argv[2:]

currlinks = os.listdir(target)
compare = []
for dr in sources:
    for f in os.listdir(dr):
        compare.append(f)
        if not f in currlinks:
            # create link
            os.symlink(dr+"/"+f, target+"/"+f)
# clean up possible broken links
for link in currlinks:
    if not link in compare:
        os.remove(target+"/"+link)
```

Choose: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts". Click the "+" and add the command yo a key combination of your choice:

```
python3 /path/to/library_view.py /path/to/virtual_library /path/to/source1 /path/to/source2
```

Comment: Jacob, I really have to thank you for going all out and writing a script for me. Now I have to use it, you did the work. :-). I'll give this a shot over the weekend. Many thanks.

Comment: @DanHutter Thanks! Hope you'll like it. If there is anything, please let me know.

Comment: Hi Jacob, I just upgraded to Ubuntu Gnome 16.10 this script still works perfectly. Currently using it for Music, Photos, and Documents!  Thank you again.

Comment: @DanHutter Thanks for mentioning, that is so good to hear!

Answer (score 3):

You can install `unionfs-fuse` for this:

```
sudo apt-get install unionfs-fuse
```

**Mounting:**

```
unionfs-fuse /folder1=RW:/folder2=RW /mount/point
```

It will group all content from **folder1** and **folder2** (or more if you want) to your mount point

**Umounting:**

```
sudo umount /mount/point
```