# File manager that supports `libraries`

Tags: software-recommendation, filesystem, partitioning

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 along with Windows 10 and it's working fine. I created a 4th partition of "Data", with ntfs type so I can put music, documents, movies, etc. Is it possible to make the default "Documents" folder in Ubuntu point to "Data/Documents", in such a way that whenever I click in "Documents" the system shows me "Data/Documents" instead of "home/Documents"? I want something similiar to Window's library feature. Is there any file manager that can do that? I`m not very good with terminal just yet... Thanks!

Comment: The question is a bit mixed up. what you mention to be like windows "libraries" is quite different, more like https://askubuntu.com/questions/766743/make-folder-a-symbolic-link-to-two-folders/766759. What you actually ask is more like: https://askubuntu.com/questions/67044/change-default-user-folders-path.

Comment: Another version of linking, partition(s) mounted in fstab. https://askubuntu.com/questions/524943/dual-boot-with-ssd-and-hdd-storage & https://askubuntu.com/questions/921778/windows-10-dual-boot-ubuntu-on-ssd-and-data-on-hdd